# outerjoin which returns all joined rows in right table if at least one matches a condition

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have two mysql tables,

```
class Item(Base):
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)

class ItemVariant(Base):
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)    
    item_id = Column(BigInteger(), nullable=False, index=True)
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)

    @declared_attr
    def item(self):
        return relationship(
            'Item',
            lazy='select',
            uselist=False,
            primaryjoin=lambda: foreign(self.item_id) == remote(Item.id),
            backref=backref('variants', uselist=True)
        )
```

ItemVariants do not necessarily need to exist for every Item. I intentionally and explicitly do not want to add foreign key constraints.

I'd like to select `(item, [list of item_variants with item_variant.item_id == item.id])`, with either `item.updated_at > some_date` or *any one of* `item_variant.update_at > some_date`.

A query like

```
session.query(
  *my_columns_with_aliases
).select_from(
  Item
).filter(
  or_(
    Item.updated_at > some_date,
    ItemVariant.updated_at > some_date
  )
).outerjoin(
  ItemVariant, ItemVariant.item_id == Item.id
)
```

doesn't work, because if I have `item_1` with `var_1, var_2`, and only `var_1.updated_at` matches the condition, `var_2` won't be included in the query results.

I've also tried doing a second aliased outerjoin for the filtering (using the non-aliased table for the selects), but this returns too many results.

Is there a standard solution for "getting all variants if at least one matches the condition"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up splitting it into two queries and using `union_all`.